# How to make dashboard in odoo 11?

Tags: odoo-11

I got no any errors but It shows nothing on dashboard view.

I added this file in the manifest file and added board module in depends.

I am trying to add project tree view in dashboard.

Here is My Code  ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="project_project_tree">
                <field name="model">project.project</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="user_id"/>
                    </tree>
                </field>
            </record>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="project_tree_view_action">
                <field name="name">Project</field>
                <field name="res_model">project.project</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
                <field name="domain">[('name','!=',False)]</field>
                <field name="view_id" ref="project_project_tree"/>
            </record>

            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="project_all_view_dashboard">
                <field name="name">Session Dashboard Form</field>
                <field name="model">board.board</field>
                <field name="type">form</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form string="Project Dashboard">
                        <board style="2-1">
                            <hpaned>
                                <child1>
                                    <action string="Project" name="%(project_tree_view_action)d"/>
                                </child1>
                            </hpaned>
                        </board>
                    </form>
                </field>
            </record>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="act_project_2_project_dashboard">
                <field name="name">Project Dashboard</field>
                <field name="res_model">board.board</field>
                <field name="view_type">form</field>
                <field name="view_mode">form</field>
                <field name="usage">menu</field>
                <field name="view_id" ref="project_all_view_dashboard"/>
            </record>

            <menuitem
                name="Session Dashboard" parent="project.menu_main_pm"
                action="act_project_2_project_dashboard"
                sequence="50"
                id="menu_board_session"/>
        </data>
    </odoo>
```

My View looks like ::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the form :

```
<form string="Project Dashboard">
   <board style="2-1">
      <column>
        <action 
              string="Project" 
              name="%(project_tree_view_action)d"
              view_mode="list"/>
      </column>
   </board>
</form>
```

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.